# Validating only specific capital letters

Tags: javascript, regex, jquery-validate, validation

I have a form that I am validating with the jQuery validation plugin and for a gender field I want to only accept capital F or capital M. The regexp I'm using is `(F|M){1}` but it is passing both lowercase and uppercase F and M. Is there anything else I can do to prevent the lowercase ones from being validated?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That regex looks fine to me, and the match should be case-sensitive by default.

Are you providing the `/i` modifier to the regex accidentally, which would make it case insensitive?